# Is it possible to check the root access on a device using phonegap / cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, root

I am trying to make my Cordova cross-platform check for root access before allowing it to be installed or function ? is it possible to do that using Phonegap / Crodova ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  I'm not aware of any existing capability that allows you to check whether the app has root access.

However, if there are any native APIs that enable this capability, and that logic can be wrapped in a Cordova plugin (http://plugins.cordova.io), you may be able to connect that to your app and achieve what you need.